# Azure Web Job run in separate process?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-webjobs

I have the following solution setup with 3 VS Projects all running in Azure:

```
-ASP.NET MVC site

-Azure Web Job

-C# Data Project
```

MVC site and Web Job have a reference to the Data Project. In the data project I have a `static List<>` "cache" when keeps some data in memory when called from my MVC site.

My Web Job is processing some data, then I'm attempting to clear that static cache in the Web Job itself.  Is that not possible since the Web Job simply runs in its own instance when referencing the Data Project? This appears to be what I'm seeing.

One thought I had was to expose and end point on my MVC site which could be called from my Web Job to clear it (worst case)

Any other thoughts here?

Comment: Use Redis Cache and share it between webjob and mvc project.

Comment: Thanks! However I feel Redis is overkill for my scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, one process cannot access to another one's classes and instances.

The best you can do is as you said create a mechanism to intercomunicate both processes, through an end point, a socket, a pipe or the one you best like.